# svn client config a proxy with username and password, but did not add the header proxy-authorization

Tags: http, svn, http-proxy

I has config a http proxy for svn globally

```
# .subversion/servers
[global]
http-proxy-host = 10.120.3.12
http-proxy-port = 80
http-proxy-username = test
http-proxy-password = test
http-compression = no
http-auth-types = basic;digest;negotiate
```

when I try svn co through http, the request can arrive the proxy server, but the 'proxy-authorization' did not contain in the header, so the proxy server can't get the credential.

Is there any mistakes about my config ?

Comment: What's your SVN client's version? Are you sure that your proxy users port 80?

Comment: subversion-1.7.14-14.tl2.x86_64, 
the port is correct，I try other port such as 8080 8888, but got the same problem  @bahrep